# Can Semaphores use number operations?

Tags: operating-system, semaphore

By that I mean, is it acceptable to add to or subtract from semaphores? The example I have is the following:

```
semaphore secureTarget = 7;
semaphore allClearAlert = 0;
semaphore bellAlert = 0;

Archer:

start();
wait(secureTarget);
wait(allClearAlert);
fireAtTarget();
signal(secureTarget);
wait(secureTarget - 7);
signal(bellAlert);
end();

Boy:

start();
signal(allClearAlert);
wait(bellAlert);
end();
```

Does that seem acceptable? If it helps, the initial question I'm trying to answer is:

> An archery club has seven targets.  Archers in the club must compete
>   to secure a target.  Once an archer secures her target she must wait
>   until the all-clear has been sounded before she can ﬁre. Once an
>   archer ﬁnishes ﬁring she leaves her target. The last archer to ﬁnish
>   sounds the bell that signiﬁes that all have ﬁnished ﬁring. Only then
>   is it safe for the small boy who collects the arrows to venture forth.
>   When all the arrows have been collected the boy gets out of the ﬁring
>   lines and sounds the all-clear to the archers.

Answer (score 2):

Semaphores can only be incremented using the signal() and wait() methods, you can't explictly change the variable as you describe. I can't give the solution explictly  - looking at your history I think I'm doing the same coursework for the same module and I don't want to be done for plagiarism, but you may find the [Little Book of Semaphores](http://greenteapress.com/semaphores/downey08semaphores.pdf) useful.

EDIT: you don't have to just use semaphores. You can use other types of shared data, as long as you use a mutex semaphore to control concurrent access to those variables.